# How to disallow a digit repeating n times with a regular expression

Tags: regex, bean-validation

Here is my @Pattern annotation.  I want to disallow digits that repeat 9 times.  What have I done wrong?

```
@Pattern(regexp="(?!.*\\d{9})")
```

These would be invalid strings:

```
111111111
222222222
```

These would be valid:

```
111111112
222222221
123456789
```

Only strings with a length of 9 will be valid but this is not needed as part of the regular expression since that will be controlled by other annotations.

Comment: What does disallow mean to you? Delete? Stop execution? Call the cops?

Comment: So do you want characters that are < 9 recurrences or > 9 recurrences?

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring.

Comment: Provide us with example strings - both positive and negative. Is `123456789` supposed to be matched? How about `abcdef` (it's not a sequence of 9 digits, but I **guess** you don't want that to match either)

Comment: The @Pattern annotation takes a regexp argument that the variable which the annotation is applied to must match or possibly not match depending on your regexp argument value.  The jsr 303 framework sets an error message based on the result of the validation performed based on the @Pattern argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited following the comments**

I think you meant you don't want the **same** digit repeating 9 times. To do that, you need to capture one digit, and refer to that and see if it repeats for 8 more times.

```
@Pattern(regexp="^(?!(\\d)\\1{8})")
```

If you simply use `\\d{9}`, it will mean repeatition of **any** digits.

Note also that you don't need `.*`. Regex will decide where to start the match on its own.

Comment: This is close, but you need to add a `^` anchor to the beginning, (i.e. `"^(?!(\\d)\\1{8})"`), otherwise, the regex will successfully, (and erroneously) match at the second char position. (depending on which regex matching function is being employed.) Otherwise good answer.

Comment: @ridgerunner: How? coder stated that strings are guaranteed to be 9 digits by the time they get to this point. Seems to me that would eliminate the opportunity for it to match starting at a second character or further.

Comment: It may be that the pattern is used to match the whole string anyway; this depends on the implementation of the validator. If it is not matched as a whole, then anchoring the pattern at the start (using the `^` anchor) might improve performance for strings not matching the pattern: Without the anchor, the regex engine will proceed to match the `\d` against one character after the other, until the end of the string.

Comment: All comments by @ridgerunner, @josh.trow, and @Christian are helpful. I actually didn't have that deep though pointed out by either of the three comments.

Comment: @Christian I suppose it all depends on how good the regex engine is at figuring out when to quit, good point though.

Comment: @josh.trow: Given the 9 digit string: `111111111`, and the pattern: `(?!(\d)\1{8})` it is true that this does not match at the first location (before the first char), because there are indeed 9 consecutive digits. The pattern within the negative assertion is true so the match _at this location within the string_ is false. However, without the `^` anchor at the start of the pattern the regex engine does not give up there. It then trys to match the pattern at _the second location_ where there are only 8 consecutive digits. This allows the overall pattern to match and a true result is returned.